# Decision tree completeness and unclassified data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

I made a program that trains a decision tree built on the **ID3** algorithm using an **information gain** function (**Shanon entropy**) for feature selection (split).
Once I trained a decision tree I tested it to classify unseen data and I realized that some data instances cannot be classified: **there is no path on the tree that classifies the instance**.

An example (this is an illustration example but I encounter the same problem with a larger and more complex data set):

- Being **f1** and **f2** the predictor variables (features) and **y** the categorical variable, the values ranges are:

  - **f1**: [`a1`; `a2`; `a3`]
  - **f2**: [`b1`; `b2`; `b3`]
  - **y** : [`y1`; `y2`; `y3`]
- Training data:

  ```
  ("a1", "b1", "y1");
  ("a1", "b2", "y2");
  ("a2", "b3", "y3");
  ("a3", "b3", "y1");
  ```
- Trained tree:

  ```
       [f2] 
      / |  \ 
    b1  b2  b3 
    /    |   \ 
   y1   y2   [f1] 
             /  \ 
            a2   a3 
           /      \ 
          y3       y1
  ```

The instance `("a1", "b3")` cannot be classified with the given tree.
Several questions came up to me:

1. Does this situation have a name? *tree incompleteness* or something like that?
2. Is there a way to know if a decision tree will cover all combinations of unknown instances (all features values combinations)?
3. Does the reason of this *"incompleteness"* lie on the topology of the data set or on the algorithm used to train the decision tree (*ID3* in this case) (or other)?
4. Is there a method to classify these *unclassifiable* instances with the given decision tree? or one must use another tool (random forest, neural networks...)?

Comment: What software are you using for learning? This situation cannot occur with decision-tree learning algorithms, because each time the algorithm makes a split, it creates a new node for every possible value of the attribute on which it split the leaf.

Comment: @blazs I made my own implementation (for learning reasons, in F# btw). For each selected feature I only take the feature values in the data subset, that's why I only have `a2` and `a3` for **f1**. If I take all the possible values for each feature, what class (**y**) value should I take for an empty subset (**f1** =`a1`)?

Comment: @polduran, that's a good question. One option would be to take the majority class of the examples that fall through the parent node. (It's much better to gather enough data to cover all cases. But I guess that's not an option in your case.)

Comment: @blazs yes that could be a good option. My first though was that I didn't implement the algorithm correctly but as I can see (after further reading) handling those kind of "marginal" cases depend on the implementation: create a "failure" terminal node, which can be similar to my case, ie. some unseen instances may not be classified; or find a way to assign a class to that feature value.

Comment: yes, machine learning involves lots of edge cases that should be handled depending on the scenario at hand. Another interesting things that occur with decision trees include: (1) what to do if you encounter a continuous attribute; (2) what if an attribute value of an example is missing (and you can't classify it); (3) information gain overestimates multi-valued attributes; etc.

Comment: (Do consider accepting the answer if it solved the problem/answered the question satisfactorily. :-)

Comment: @blazs good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation cannot occur with the ID3 decision-tree learner---regardless of whether it uses information gain or some other heuristic for split selection. (See, for example, [ID3 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm) on Wikipedia.)

The "trained tree" in your example above could not have been returned by the ID3 decision-tree learning algorithm.

This is because when the algorithm selects a `d`-valued attribute (i.e. an attribute with `d` possible values) on which to split the given leaf, it will create `d` new children (one per attribute value). In particular, in your example above, the node `[f1]` would have three children, corresponding to attribute values `a1`,`a2`, and `a3`.

It follows from the previous paragraph (and, in general, from the way the ID3 algorithm works) that any well-formed vector---of the form `(v1, v2, ..., vn, y)`, where `vi` is a value of `i`-th attribute and `y` is the class value---should be classifiable by the decision tree that the algorithm learns on a given train set.

Would you mind providing a link to the software you used to learn the "incomplete" trees?

To answer your questions:

1. Not that I know of. It doesn't make sense to learn such "incomplete trees." If we knew that some attribute values will never occur then we would not include them in the specification (the file where you list attributes and their values) in the first place.
2. With the ID3 algorithm, you can prove---as I sketched in the answer---that every tree returned by the algorithm will cover all possible combinations.
3. You're using the wrong algorithm. Data has nothing to do with it.
4. There is no such thing as an unclassifiable instance in decision-tree learning. One usually defines a decision-tree learning problem as follows. Given a train set `S` of examples `x1,x2,...,xn` of the form `xi=(v1i,v2i,...,vni,yi)` where `vji` is the value of the `j`-th attribute and `yi` is the class value in example `xi`, learn a function (represented by a decision tree) `f: X -> Y`, where `X` is the space of all possible well-formed vectors (i.e. all possible combinations of attribute values) and `Y` is the space of all possible class values, which minimizes an error function (e.g. the number of misclassified examples). From this definition, you can see that one requires that the function `f` is able to map any combination to a class value; thus, by definition, each possible instance is classifiable.